# Is there any less popular web3 development platform?

Tags: web3js, tools

I want to try out some less popular web3 development platforms. Any suggestion? I have tried the following and that is all I can find online.

1. Truffle
2. Remix
3. Hardhat
4. OpenZepplin
5. Ganache
6. Tenderly

Answer (score 1):

Some other popular development platforms are [`foundry`](https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry) and [`apeworx`](https://www.apeworx.io/) the sucessor of brownie. You can find a list on the `Ethereum.org` [website](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/local-environment/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ser. 
I have upvoted your answer but I would still like to keep this question open for discussion.